# concatenate 2 object arrays to one

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object array containing one property call `name` like this

```
var nameArr = [  
   {  
      "name":"john"
   },
   {  
      "name":"carl"
   },
   {  
      "name":"peter"
   }
]
```

I have a another array called `ageArr` and it only contain property called `age`

```
var ageArr = [  
   {  
      "age":"22"
   },
   {  
      "age":"21"
   },
   {  
      "age":"32"
   }
]
```

i want to concat these array and end result should result like this

```
var result = [  
   {  
      "age":"22",
      "name":"john"
   },
   {  
      "age":"21",
      "name":"carl"
   },
   {  
      "age":"32",
      "name":"peter"
   }
]
```

note that length of the both arrays always equal and dynamic. Is there any way i can do this without looping these array inside one another. Thank you.

Comment: `for`, `forEach`, `map`, ...

Comment: `var result = nameArr.map((name, index) => Object.assign({}, name, ageArr[index]));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Object.assign()` and `map()` and return new array.

```js
var nameArr = [{"name":"john"},{"name":"carl"},{"name":"peter"}]
var ageArr = [{"age":"22"},{"age":"21"},{"age":"32"}]

var result = nameArr.map(function(e, i) {
  return Object.assign({}, e, ageArr[i])
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Single `forEach()` function is enough.

```js
var nameArr=[{name:"john"},{name:"carl"},{name:"peter"}],
    ageArr=[{age:"22"},{age:"21"},{age:"32"}];


nameArr.forEach((v,i) => v.age = ageArr[i].age)
console.log(nameArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code snippet.

```
var result = nameArr.map(function( obj, index ) {
    var res = ageArr[index];
    res.name = obj.name;
    return res;
});
```

In the map, you can easily use

> jQuery.extend()

to create a merge of two same index object.